# I changed "python.exe" to "python3.exe" but now pip returns an error, how can i fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, environment-variables, python-2.x

So in order to make my life easier, I changed Python 2.7 to "python2.exe and Python 3.6 to "python3.exe". I then added them to my path and am able to reference them in which `python2` opens Python 2.7 and `python3` opens Python 3.6.

This is exactly what I want but now since I changed the names the `pip` command returns this:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

I still want to be able to reference `python3` and run Python 3.6, but I need pip to work. Do I change a pip file to reference it? or is it something else? Please help if you can.

Comment: rename everything back to make your life even easier (:

Comment: @Aiven But then there are conflicts with Python 2.7 and Python 3.6

Comment: In the Linux world, you have a python3.6 "exe" and a shortcut python3 to it, both in your PATH.

Comment: How about having 2 accounts, or 2 shell shortcuts that have paths to the different pythons?

Comment: Look into something like anaconda.  You can have separate environments for any version of python you wish to use.

Comment: If one of you could explain this better that would be great, it's a bit confusing but seems like a good solution.

Comment: @chrisz That sounds interesting, could you explain a bit more? I've used anaconda before but never with 2 versions like that.

Comment: You can do something like `conda create -n myenv python=3.4` which creates an environment using python 3.4, and so forth.

Comment: Using virtualenv would also help you https://www.google.com.au/search?ei=-JVSWvyIK4mk8AWT1r3AAw&q=virtual+environment+python+3&oq=virtual+environment+python+3&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l5j0i10k1j0l3.5532.7934.0.8422.9.7.0.2.2.0.248.1260.0j1j5.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.8.1283...0i67k1.0.CcpMwYqRzh4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend you change the names back, because numerous scripts (pip likely included) expect the original filename.

To make your life easier when launching python files on windows, python comes with a more flexible solution. If you have a recent python3 installed on windows, the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) should be installed as well. That means you can run python 2 and 3 scripts with a `py <file>` command. The launcher respects shebang lines specifying the python version or you can pass a flag to choose the version manually: `py -2 <file>`